# iterator dereferencing issue

Tags: c++, iterator

if I have

```
list<NS*> v;  
typename list<NS*>::iterator it;   
for(it = v.begin();it!=v.end();++it){  
  cout<<**it.ns_member1<<endl;    // does not compile  
  NS ns = **it;  
  cout<<ns.ns_member1<<endl;      // this compiles.  
}
```

Why so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dereference (the '*') has a lower precedence than the '.' operator, so this line:

```
cout<<**it.ns_member1<<endl;
```

Works out like this:

```
cout << (**(it.ns_member1)) <<endl; // ERROR
```

I would suggest doing it like this:

```
cout << (*it)->ns_member1 << endl;
```

There is really no need to use the dereference operator twice, once followed by the '->' operator will do the same thing and should read clearer to most people.

HTH.

Answer (score 3):

Try `(**it).ns_member1`.

Otherwise, the dereferencing would be done after trying to evaluate `it.ns_member1`. It's like `3*(1+2)` vs `3*1+2`.